# PHP Composer unable to update: composer.json missing?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I was working on a laravel project and wanted to add a dependency calling

`[laravel-school]$ composer require {dependecy}`

and whatever composer action I call inside my project's directory I get the message

```
[laravel-school]$ composer update
Composer could not find the config file: /home/[username]/.composer/vendor/bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

What I don't get is: I have a composer.json file in the right place, the project's root.

How I got there:
I did setup the laravel project via 

`laravel new {project}`

A short overview of what I have installed:

```
$ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer

[laravel-school]$ ls
app        composer.json  gulpfile.js   phpunit.xml  resources   tests
artisan    config         package.json  public       server.php  vendor
bootstrap  database       phpspec.yml   readme.md    storage
```

Comment: Check the permission on `/home/[username]/.composer/` maybe? That's where composer keeps its config and cache

Comment: "composer update --no-scripts " did work on tghe homestead machine i just choose to use from now one (to keep the workflow aligned to my windows workstation at home and my ol macbook)